# Should function returned in hook be wrapped in useCallback?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

From what I see, I should not need to wrap state actions in `useCallback`, but should I wrap the `resetWidgetCount` function in `useCallback` and set the dependency to `setWidgetCount`?

[Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-hodgkin-7k5zb3?file=/src/App.tsx:0-771)

```
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const useWidget = () => {
  const [widgetCount, setWidgetCount] = useState<number>(0);

  // should this be wrapped in useCallback
  const resetWidgetCount = useCallback(() => {
    setWidgetCount(0);
  }, [setWidgetCount]);

  return {
    widgetCount,
    setWidgetCount,
    resetWidgetCount
  };
};

export default function App() {
  const { widgetCount, setWidgetCount, resetWidgetCount } = useWidget();

  const handleIncrement = () =>
    setWidgetCount((prevState: number) => prevState + 1);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>Count: {widgetCount}</div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleIncrement}>Increment</button>{" "}
        <button onClick={resetWidgetCount}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You should wrap it but. You shouldn't put setWidgetCount in the dependecies array because react guarantee that state setter would not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a component is rendered, all existing functions inside its body are recreated unless they are `useCallback`, in this case react will check the values in the hook's dependency array and will compare to what they were in the last render.
 if one or more have been modified, the function is recreated.

That being said, giving `useCallback` an empty dependency array `[]` or a dependepency array with a function that never updates remains the same, the hook will fire only once during the component first mount.
it is the case here, `setWidgetCount` is a useState setter function so its identity is stable